# Liskov substitution principle VS Interface Segregation principle

Tags: java, oop, liskov-substitution-principle, interface-segregation-principle

I have some troubles with understanding these two principles. This is a bit long-read-question, so be patient.

Lets assume that we have a class

```
abstract class Shape {
    abstract void onDraw();
}
```

and interface

```
interface SideCountable {
  int getSidesCount();
}
```

And then we create two children classes

```
class Quad extends Shape {

   @Override
   public void onDraw() {
   //some draw logic here
   }
}

class Triangle extends Shape {

   @Override
   public void onDraw() {
   //some draw logic here
   }
}
```

And now we will make `Shape` implements `SideCountable`

```
abstract class Shape implements SideCountable{
    abstract void onDraw();
}
```

and make changes in children classes

```
class Quad extends Shape {

   @Override
   public int getSidesCount() {
       return 4;
   }

   @Override
   public void onDraw() {
   //some draw logic here
   }
}

class Triangle extends Shape {

   public int getSidesCount() {
       return 3;
   }

   public void onDraw() {
   //some draw logic here
   }
}
```

And create test function for this structure (following LSP) :

```
public void printSidesCount(List<Shape> shapes) {
    for(int i=0; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(shapes.get(i).getSidesCount());
    }
}
```

And here I want to stop because actually in the next step I was stucked.
What if we'll create a third class `Circle`?

```
class Circle extends Shape {

   public int getSidesCount() {
       return ???;
   }

   @Override
   public void onDraw() {
   //some draw logic here
   }
}
```

Circle has no sides, so implementation of `SideCountable` for this children sounds ridiculous. Ok, we can move implementation to Quad and Triangle only, but in this case LSP will not working anymore. Can someone describe what the best way I should to do?

- Leave `SideCountable` in `Shape` class and return 0 for `Circle` and break interface segregation principle?
- Move `SideCountable` to `Quad` and `Triangle` and break LSP principle?

Comment: Just as a note, the Liskov Substitution principle really doesn't apply to this kind of setup - it's supposed to provide an abstraction for classes that all provide the same result with different implementations. A `Quad` and a `Triangle` will never provide the same side count. Different `Quad` implementations will, which is when Liskov Substitution is fulfilled.

Comment: @daniu Yes, you're right. My bad.

Comment: `Circle` could have a child `CircumscribedCircle` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle), which, for `getSidesCount`, could return its polygon sides. So it also depends on your domain, and how profound your hierarchy is. But a general piece of advice, as @Jesper put it, would be not putting too specific interfaces (`SideCountable`) on top of too abstract classes (`Shape`) unless your domain is well-defined and you perfectly know what children could be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your method `printSidesCount` only needs to know that the list contains `SideCountable` objects. So giving its parameter the type `List<Shape>` is more specific than necessary. Give it a `List<SideCountable>` instead:

```
public void printSidesCount(List<SideCountable> sideCountables) {
    for(int i=0; i < (); i++) {
        System.out.println(sideCountables.get(i).getSidesCount());
    }
}
```

Or even `List<? extends SideCountable>` which means "a list of some arbitrary unknown type that implements `SideCountable`":

```
public void printSidesCount(List<? extends SideCountable> sideCountables) {
    for(int i=0; i < sideCountables.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(sideCountables.get(i).getSidesCount());
    }
}
```

If not all shapes have a countable number of sides, then class `Shape` should not implement interface `SideCountable`. Instead, make classes `Quad` and `Triangle` implement interface `SideCountable` besides extending class `Shape`:

```
class Quad extends Shape implements SideCountable {
    // ...
}

class Triangle extends Shape implements SideCountable {
    // ...
}
```

And make class `Circle` extend `Shape` but not implement `SideCountable`:

```
class Circle extends Shape { // Not SideCountable
    // ...
}
```

When you do it like this, the type system will help you:

- you can pass a `List<Quad>` or `List<Triangle>` to `printSidesCount` since those types implement `SideCountable`
- you cannot pass a `List<Circle>` to `printSidesCount`, which is good because trying to do this would not make sense for a list of circles